# How to get a data authenticated page using web client

Tags: java, httpclient, webclient, httpurlconnection

I am using web client for getting page source. I have logged in successfully. After that, I use same object for getting page source using different URL but it's showing an Exception like:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.UnexpectedPage cannot be cast to com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage
```

This is the code which i am using.

```
            forms = (List<HtmlForm>) firstPage.getForms();
        form = firstPage.getFormByName("");

        HtmlTextInput usernameInput = form.getInputByName("email");
        HtmlPasswordInput passInput = form.getInputByName("password");
        HtmlHiddenInput redirectInput = form.getInputByName("redirect");
        HtmlHiddenInput submitInput = form.getInputByName("form_submit");

        usernameInput.setValueAttribute(username);
        passInput.setValueAttribute(password);

        //Create Submit Button
        HtmlElement button = firstPage.createElement("button");
        button.setAttribute("type", "submit");
        button.setAttribute("name", "submit");
        form.appendChild(button);
        System.out.println(form.asXml());
        HtmlPage pageAfterLogin = button.click();

        String sourc = pageAfterLogin.asXml();

        System.out.println(pageAfterLogin.asXml());

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

above code running successfully and login
After that i am using this code

```
    HtmlPage downloadPage = null;       
downloadPage=(HtmlPage)webClient.getPage("url");
```

But i am getting Exception

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.UnexpectedPage cannot be cast to com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage
```

Comment: Is the page being returned a valid HTML page?

Comment: yes this is valid html page return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the [JavaDoc of UnexpectedPage](http://www.netlikon.de/docs/javadoc-htmlunit/htmlunit-2.1/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/UnexpectedPage.html) they state that

> A generic page that is returned whenever an unexpected content type is
>   returned by the server.

I would advise that you check the content type of `webClient.getPage("url");`

Comment: yes you are right this exception occurred brcause of content type is mismatch. i was passing application/json content type.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
HtmlPage downloadPage = null;       
downloadPage=(HtmlPage)webClient.getPage("url");
```

Use

```
UnexpectedPage downloadPage = null;       
downloadPage=(HtmlPage)webClient.getPage("url");
```

It worked fine with me.